# Is it safe to make public md5 hash of other users' SESSID?

Tags: php, security, md5, sessionid

I have a chat application running on a php WebSocket server.

When a client connects, I send him an object with other users' id and nick name. I need to send those ids so that when an user says something, or disconnects, etc., other users can know who has said that, or has disconnected, etc.

Server-side I work with SESSID because I use `$_SESSION` data, but of course I can't make public the list of SESSID.

Then, can I use `md5($userId)` (where `$userId` is SESSID), or is it possible to hijack a session from its md5 hash?

Comment: Why not simply generating a new ID? Why does it need to be based on the session ID?

Comment: @Gumbo I knew I could do that, but then I must check if the new generated ID already belongs to another user. With `md5($userId)`, `$user_Id` is unique and since md5 hash is longer than SESSID, I guess `md5($userId)` is unique too (I was planning to ask it too in case md5 hash was safe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are not best things for security, and i wouldn't recommend it in most cases.

**But** in this case there is a difference:

All SSID's are absolute nonsense (I mean they are random) so If you add needed *salt* to make your

```
salt.length + $userId.length
```

more than 32 characters (to be on the safe side, make it more than 128 chars), it's ***logically impossible*** to decrypt the hash. decrypting it would be like remaking a file from its hash!
<sub>which is impossible</sub>

To make things easier, here is the code you need:

```
function YourNewHashMaker($str)
{
return sha1(md5("Some Random Salt".$str).$str."Another Random Salt!".sha1("This one is too much".$str));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
YourNewHashMaker($userId);
```

Only security hole here, is the possibility that someone steals your code, and starts to make a rainbow table, which is a **REALLY hard thing to do**. and also the same security hole of all other hashes.

**Edit**: Remember, whatever idea you are having to make your own *hashmakers*, remember that ***output string must be generated by an approved algorithm.*** in other words, ***Do not add anything before or after 'sha1(....)' , just inside of the function.***

Hope It Helps.

Comment: I like it. But if I understand it well, it's impossible to remake a file from its hash because there are lots of (infinity?) files which have the same hash. Then, can I be sure that different SESSID will give different results?

Comment: It's difference between All Possible Files That CAN exist(infinity), and those files that DO exist. Because the total number of all files are sure less than 26^32 files, so it would be a miracle to see two files with same hash. the same logic applies for SSID's, with much more less possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Any hash function used in this context would be insecure,  and choosing MD5 as your hash function means that you are unaware of best practices related to cryptographic functions. MD5 has been broken for many years, and should never be used for anything, ever. (Even sha1 is more secure and faster,  but you probably shouldn't be using SHA1 either).

There are many problems with this. Most notably, this should be [trivial to crack](http://www.md5crack.com/),  as any small number should be in a rainbow table.  An attacker should know every `SESSID` value.
As a session ID, use PHP's `session_start()`.   If you need a token,  use a cryptographic nonce.  If you don't understand the very basics of hash functions,  then **don't use a hash function.**

Comment: ofcourse, salting the hash would defeat the issue of the rainbow table. And calling "MD5" broken and unusable for _anything_ is a bit too much. Sure, hardcore security might not like it anymore, but as a hash, verifying a download? I don't see big issues there to be honest?

Comment: Ok, I won't use md5. But just a note: I can't use `session_start()` because then I start a session with the php websocket server script instead of with each client, so I must store the `SESSID`s server-side.

Comment: @Rook What does "*nonce*" mean? I don't think it's http://www.wordreference.com/definition/nonce